# Discord.py on_invite_create event

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Is there an discord.py event like:

```
@client.event
async def on_invite_create(invite):
```

Does something like this exist?
Ive searched in the documentation but couldnt find anything like that.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=invite#discord.on_invite_create

Answer (score 1):

There is yes, it's called exactly that. `on_invite_create` is called when an Invite is created. You must have the manage_channels permission to receive this, and Intents.invites enabled.

You can view the documentation for it [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_invite_create)